# UI rapidly slows as chart updates

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, syncfusion

I am in the midst of developing a mobile application using Xamarin.Forms. The app connects to a BLE device which transmits 16 bytes of data every 100 ms. I am plotting the data with Syncfusion in a bar chart format.

I can connect to the device and receive data without issues. But after a very small amount of time, the app starts to significantly decrease in performance. Soon hereafter, it completely stalls. Obviously I am doing something wrong in handling the incoming data (unless it is a performance issue with the Syncfusion chart).

In a nutshell, this is the process I go through in the app

1. Pair to the device (outside of the app)
2. Connect to the device (in the app)
3. Set up the transmission
4. Process the incoming data via a `Model` called SpectrogramModel
5. Graph the data with Syncfusion in a `View` called DataPage, which is bound to a `ViewModel` called DataViewModel

Getting into the nitty-gritty of it all, after pairing and connecting to the device, the following method is called. Could it be the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` call which eventually starts blocking the app? This method is called from a `Connection` class, which has a reference to the DataViewModel

```
private void UpdateSpectrogramChart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DebugHelper.Message(Type.Method, "UpdateSpectrogramChart");

        _characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
        {
            var raw = args.Characteristic.Value;

            for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Level[{0}] = {1}", i, raw[i]);
            }

            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DataPageViewModel.Levels.Clear();

                for (int i = SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset; i < raw.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewRawData)
                    {
                        DataPageViewModel.Title = "Raw data";

                        DataPageViewModel
                        .Levels
                        .Add(
                            new SpectrogramModel(
                                raw[i],
                                1 + (i - SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset))
                                );
                    }
                    if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewProcessedData)
                    {
                        DataPageViewModel.Title = "Processed data";

                        DataPageViewModel
                        .Levels
                        .Add(
                            new SpectrogramModel(
                                raw[i],
                                1 + (i - SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset),
                                i));
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

The SpectrogramModel looks like this

```
public class SpectrogramModel
{
    public SpectrogramModel(byte level, int frequency)
    {
        Level = level;
        Frequency = frequency;
    }

    public SpectrogramModel(byte level, int frequency, int index) : this(level, frequency)
    {
        Level = ProcessRawLevel(level, index);
    }

    private double ProcessRawLevel(byte b, int index)
    {
        double multiplier = 0.75;
        double val = b;
        val *= multiplier;
        return val;
    }

    public static readonly int FrequencyOffset = 4;

    ...
```

The DataPage looks like this

```
<chart:SfChart>

        <chart:SfChart.Title>
            <chart:ChartTitle
                        Text="{Binding Title}">
            </chart:ChartTitle>
        </chart:SfChart.Title>

        <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

            <chart:CategoryAxis>
            </chart:CategoryAxis>

        </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

        <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

            <chart:NumericalAxis
                Minimum="20" 
                Maximum="100">
            </chart:NumericalAxis>

        </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

        <chart:SfChart.Series>

            <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}" XBindingPath="Frequency" YBindingPath="Level"/>

        </chart:SfChart.Series>

    </chart:SfChart>
```

Finally, the DataViewModel which the DataPage is bound

```
public class DataViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public DataViewModel()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Levels = new ObservableCollection<SpectrogramModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) Levels.Add(new SpectrogramModel(20, i));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SpectrogramModel> _levels;
    public ObservableCollection<SpectrogramModel> Levels
    {
        get { return _levels; ; }
        set
        {
            _levels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the `UpdateSpectrogramChart()` is wrapped in a timer, which looks like this

```
public void InitTimers()
    {
        DebugHelper.Message(Type.Method, "InitTimers");
        int SECOND = 1000 * 2;
        SpectrogramChartTimer = new Timer();
        SpectrogramChartTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateSpectrogramChart);
        SpectrogramChartTimer.Interval = SECOND;
    }
```

I wrapped the call to the `UpdateSpectrogramChart()` method in a (clear) failed attempt to reduce the performance decrease.

For completeness sake, here is the method body of the method which sets up receiving from the BLE device

```
public async Task ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic(string service, string characteristic, string descriptor = null)
    {
        DebugHelper.Message(Type.Method, "ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic");

        bleAdapter.DeviceConnected += async (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "bleAdapter.DeviceConected += async (s, e) ...");

                string[] deviceInfo = { e.Device.Name, e.Device.Id.ToString() };

                // Connect to service
                try
                {
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "Connecting to service...");
                    _service = await e.Device.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse(service));
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "OK");
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Could not connect to service");
                }

                // Connect to characteristic
                try
                {
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "Connecting to characteristic...");
                    _characteristic = await _service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(characteristic));
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "OK");
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Could not connect to characteristic");
                }

                await ConfigureSpectrogram(UpdateFrequency.High, 0x1);

                try
                {
                    await _characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
                }

                catch
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Error starting UpdatesAsync");
                }

                _characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                {
                    var raw = args.Characteristic.Value;

                    for (int i = 4; i < raw.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Level[{0}] = {1}", i - 4, raw[i]);
                    }
                };
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Error in ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Maybe put everything in a background thread and then make only the UI changes on MainThread?

Comment: @G.hakim I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do let me know if it does not work for you so, I can help you out maybe!

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you! I am trying it out right now. I am new to working with Threads so it might take some doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this *really* qualifies as an answer but I seem to have solved the problem although I can't say for sure why this has solved it.

After fiddling with a `BackgroundWorker`, which introduced even more errors (probably because I am no expert on the usage of it), I revised the code and moved the update of the `Model` and the `View` directly into the `ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic()`, method instead of updating the `Model` and the `View` in a separate method, as follows:

```
public void ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic(string service, string characteristic, string descriptor = null)
    {
        DebugHelper.Message(Type.Method, "ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic");

        bleAdapter.DeviceConnected += async (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "bleAdapter.DeviceConected += async (s, e) ...");

                string[] deviceInfo = { e.Device.Name, e.Device.Id.ToString() };

                // Connect to service
                try
                {
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "Connecting to service...");
                    _service = await e.Device.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse(service));
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "OK");
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Could not connect to service");
                }

                // Connect to characteristic
                try
                {
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "Connecting to characteristic...");
                    _characteristic = await _service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(characteristic));
                    DebugHelper.Message(Type.Info, "OK");
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Could not connect to characteristic");
                }

                await ConfigureSpectrogram(UpdateFrequency.High, 0x1);

                try
                {
                    await _characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
                }

                catch
                {
                    DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Error starting UpdatesAsync");
                }
                // ADDITION
                _characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                {
                    var raw = args.Characteristic.Value;

                    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        DataPageViewModel.Levels.Clear();

                        for (int i = Models.Spectrogram.FrequencyOffset; i < raw.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewRawData)
                            {
                                DataPageViewModel.Title = "Raw data";

                                DataPageViewModel
                                .Levels
                                .Add(
                                    new Models.Spectrogram(
                                        raw[i],
                                        1 + (i - Models.Spectrogram.FrequencyOffset))
                                        );
                            }

                            if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewProcessedData)
                            {
                                DataPageViewModel.Title = "Processed data";

                                DataPageViewModel
                                .Levels
                                .Add(
                                    new Models.Spectrogram(
                                        raw[i],
                                        1 + (i - Models.Spectrogram.FrequencyOffset),
                                        i));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
            }
            // END OF ADDITION

            catch (Exception)
            {
                DebugHelper.Error(ErrorType.GATT, "Error in ReceiveFromGattCharacteristic");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We would like to let you know that some of the SfChart configuration need to consider while using huge amount of data and increasing the performance.

1. Make use of SuspendSeriesNotification and ResumeSeriesNoification.

We can stop the chart from being updated for each modification in the items source collection. By using SuspendSeriesNotification and ResumeSeriesNotification methods.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DataPageViewModel.Levels.Clear();

Chart.SuspendSeriesNotification();

                for (int i = SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset; i < raw.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewRawData)
                    {
                        DataPageViewModel.Title = "Raw data";

                        DataPageViewModel
                        .Levels
                        .Add(
                            new SpectrogramModel(
                                raw[i],
                                1 + (i - SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset))
                                );
                    }
                    if (SettingsViewModel.IsViewProcessedData)
                    {
                        DataPageViewModel.Title = "Processed data";

                        DataPageViewModel
                        .Levels
                        .Add(
                            new SpectrogramModel(
                                raw[i],
                                1 + (i - SpectrogramModel.FrequencyOffset),
                                i));
                    }
                }
Chart.ResumeSeriesNotification();
            });
```

2. Avoid use of Category Axis.

We have figured that you are using Category axis with column series. We always suggested to use Numeric or datetime axis with fast line series to get better performance. If you really need the category axis and column series, please let us know how many data your chart will load or any reason to use of category axis.

Some of the tips to get better performance from SfChart, please read the below blog. 
https://blog.syncfusion.com/post/7-tips-to-optimize-xamarin-charts-performance.aspx#comment-10677

Regards,
Bharathi.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Bharathi. I will surely consider your tips for performance optimization. However, like I posted above, I have already solved the issue, and as you can see, it was *not* a performance issue with the chart. Secondly, there is a reason why I use a ColumnSeries to plot the data: it's because I need to plot the data in that format.